# Reversing multiplication operator in c++

Tags: c++, multiplication

I am attempting to reverse an application's deserializer, and I'm mostly finished, but I'm stuck at this issue. The application, for whatever reason, decodes 4-byte numbers by multiplying it by an encode key (or decode key for that matter)

```
int decoded_number = (encode_key * encoded_number);
```

This works for decoding their numbers, however, I am more interested in encoding numbers, so I can serialize data. I have tried encoding the number by multiplying a decoded number with the encode key

```
int encoded_number = (encode_key * decoded_number);
```

However, when I compare it to the original encoded number, it's completely different. I have also attempted to bruteforce-encode the number, and it works, but takes forever to generate the number, which is not feasible when serializing lots of numbers.

```cpp
for (int i = INT_MIN; i < INT_MAX; i++){
  if (i * encode_key == decoded_number)
    return i; /* "i" is the encoded number */
}
```

At this point, I have no idea what else to try. My code is below:

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int encode_key = -381784151; /* Key I took from the application */
int encoded_numbers[2] = {-810310503, 1520670208}; /* Numbers I took from the app */

int bruteforce(int decoded_number){
    for (int i = -2147483648; i < 2147483647; i++){ /* min and max int*/
        if (encode_key * i == decoded_number){ /* brute comparison */
            return i;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        int encoded_number = encoded_numbers[i];
        int decoded_number = encode_key * encoded_number;
        int attempt_encode = encode_key * decoded_number;
        int brute_encode = bruteforce(decoded_number);

        cout << "STARTING WITH NUMBER" << i+1 << "\n";
        cout << "Encoded Number: " << encoded_number << "\n";
        cout << "Decoded Number: " << decoded_number << "\n";
        cout << "Attempt to Re-Encode (FAIL): " << attempt_encode << "\n";
        cout << "Bruteforce Encode (SLOW!): " << brute_encode << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Click here to run the code in your browser](https://onlinegdb.com/B10-xXLN4)

Comment: The reverse of multiplication is division.

Comment: The concept itself should work in C, not just C++.

Comment: Note that if `(encode_key * encoded_number)` would have overflowed during hashing it would be undefined behavior (maybe it wasn't done in c++?). The same is true for your attempts at reversing the hash. Edit : So if `encode_key` is anything bigger than 1, `i * encode_key == decoded_number` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Barmar the result of the multiplication exceeds the 4-byte limit, so division would not work in this case.

Comment: @JanaSchweizer In c++, for `signed` integral types it is. Since any result of a multiplication that would overflow is undefined anyway. Edit : If want to implement some form of modulo multiplication with `signed` integers you will first have to decide how you want it to work and then implement it yourself.

Comment: @JanaSchweizer Then the multiplication produces undefined behavior. You need to use `unsigned int` if you want modular arithmetic.

Comment: also `encode_key * i` will overflow in your loop (actually for most values of `i`)

Comment: Modular multiplication can't be easily inverted. See [modular division](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-division/)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm really just looking for an almost instantaneous way to recreate a similar encoded_number without bruteforcing, because there are many different combinations from INT_MIN to INT_MAX that can be used.

Comment: In general, hashes are one-way operations and can't be reversed uniquely.

Comment: isnt that the whole point of encryption, that it is difficult to calculate the reverse?

Comment: @EricPostpischil For more background, I am trying to generate save data for an application. Nothing out of malice.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, my mistake. I am trying to serialize data, not hash. :)

Comment: Why would you use multiplication by an encode key when serializing?

Comment: From what I've gathered so far, I believe it's there to secure save data, so you need the key to read it. However, I've been told that the serializer has been released online somewhere, but it's not up to date. Either way, it's really hard to claim multiplication as your own encoding algorithm. @Barmar

Comment: The multiplicative inverse of -381784151 modulo 2^32 is 491758745. This means that if y is the result of multiplying x by -381784151 and taking the low 32 bits of the result, then multiplying y by 491758745 and taking the low 32 bits of the result gives x. (This arithmetic is usually done with unsigned integers. If you use signed integers, you must ensure it wraps modulo 2^32. C and C++ do not define the behavior of signed integer overflow.)

Comment: @Barmar: Modular multiplication either can be inverted (no information is lost) or it cannot be (information is lost). If it can be, then it is easy. The method for finding the multiplicative inverse is a simple extension to the Euclidean Algorithm and requires only a few lines of code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I admit I'm not really a math expert, I thought there might not be a unique result. But I also gave a link to a site with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @EricPostpischil for a great answer. To reverse the multiplication, all you need to do is multiply the decoded number with the multiplicative inverse of key. Here is a code example featuring the solution.

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int encode_key = -381784151;
int encoded_numbers[2] = {-810310503, 1520670208};

int getinverse(int key){
    for (int i = -2147483648; i < 2147483647; i++){ /* min and max int*/
        if (key * i == 1){ /* brute comparison */
            return i;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int inverse = getinverse(encode_key); /* Grab the multiplicative inverse of encode_key */

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        int encoded_number = encoded_numbers[i];
        int decoded_number = encode_key * encoded_number;
        int attempt_encode = inverse * decoded_number; /* multiply inverse and decoded_number */

        cout << "STARTING WITH NUMBER" << i+1 << "\n";
        cout << "Encoded Number: " << encoded_number << "\n";
        cout << "Decoded Number: " << decoded_number << "\n";
        cout << "Attempt to Re-Encode (CORRECT!): " << attempt_encode << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```